# InvalidOperationException when writing xml to file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following code:

```
XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));

FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create("c:\\myexample.xml");
writer.Serialize(file, table);

file.Close();
```

I want to serialize my DataTable object to a xml file. But I am getting:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the content of 'table'?

Comment: @FirstStep it is a full path? And the \ is escaped, so no need for escaping or a verbatim `@` prefix.

Comment: I'm not sure `DataTable` can be serialised, you probably should be looking at `DataTable.WriteXml`.

Comment: Could you also check your exception's innerException property? That is where the xmlserializer will store it's "real" error when throwing an InvalidOpEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
    public void SaveToFile(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlWriter = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] { typeof(YourClass) })[0];
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path + "\\Whatever.bla"); // need file name

        xmlWriter.Serialize(writer, this);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: @АлександарПламенац Can we what your class/object includes?